# Install Windows XP on a PCI IDE Controller Card

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I need to install Windows XP on a drive on a PCI IDE Controller Card, but I can't because the Windows installer does not seem to detect it.

I know that the disk is properly installed because the prior installation of Windows loads perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a floppy drive, pay attention at the beginning of the blue colored windows setup screen. When you see a message that says “Press F6 if you need to install a third party SCSI or RAID driver…” at the bottom bar, immediately hit F6 key.
And insert your floppy with the drivers of the controller card.

If you don't have floppy drive follow this: [howtogeek.com: resolving setup did not find any hard disk drives during windows xp installation](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/resolving-setup-did-not-find-any-hard-disk-drives-during-windows-xp-installation/at) to add the drivers to a custom windows xp cd

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the text-mode xp drivers for your PCI IDE card and load them up during the blue text (a bit like dos) stage of the XP install.

Comment: Hope you've got a floppy drive somewhere.  Alternatively, you can slipstream your XP install with instructions all over the net, like this one:  http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/windowsxp_sp2_slipstream.asp